# Fix pH Value ongoing with right plant

Tags: agriculture, plant

I am a very beginning in planting three.

I sent a ground sample for analysis and one of the results is the pH value of

pH **6.2** in `water` solution and
pH **4.75** in `KCl` solution.

I am planning to seed walnut tree which likes most alkaline ground rather than acidic.

One of the solutions for fixing Ph value is to put limestone in the ground but this needs at least 2 years to finish part of the process and also can affect microelements in the ground like Iron or Boron.

Assuming that current pH value is ok to start with planting
I would like to ask if there is some plant that can make ground alkaline and also Walnut friendly.

Or in other words, is there a combination of plants with Walnut that can help each other to use the best from the ground without artificial ground fixing?

Comment: It might be better to ask this question on [SE Gardening & Landscaping](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/). There I found this question, [Is it possible to modify soil pH with plants?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/33765/is-it-possible-to-modify-soil-ph-with-plants)

Comment: all you need to do is to mix in some limestone into the soil you plant the tree in,trees grow so slowly that you will have plenty of time to add limestone as the tree grows,limestone dissolves fast when the soil is acidic and you do not need to make the soil alcaline before you plant your tree,your tree wil grow fine in neutralized soil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pH of 6.2 is pretty acidic for soil . A more obvious method to lower acid would be limestone as gravel. And for a fast start ,add lime powder, available at any agriculture supply. Rototilling would be good ,but just sprinkling on the surface would be some help.  You can measure soil pH yourself easily. Put a soil sample in distilled water and shake in a sealed container ( to avoid CO 2 from the atmosphere ) .Then get pH indicator solution from a pet shop ( bromthymol blue ?) and test the water after the soil settles. Aquarium water is routinely tested with this indicator.